# SoundJS: Why can't FireFox play mp3 file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, soundjs

When I try to play a sound ,that is a mp3, like this:

```
createjs.Sound.registerSound('uploads/songs/test.mp3','song');
```

It gives me this error in FireFox (Chrome works fine):

> The buffer passed to `decodeAudioData` contains an unknown content type

Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix this?

PS: Using a .Ogg file works but I really need mp3 to work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a [known issue](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/WebAudioPlugin.html) with Firefox on windows that does not load all mp3 files properly, and therefore it is recommended that you load another supported file type first (such as ogg).

Hope that helps.